# What makes any linear function linear?

Tags: reference-request

Is it the fact that the function's graph includes a **non cursive line** (but not necessarily a totally straight line)?

Is it something else?

Comment: See [Linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function)

Comment: Its definition. Please ask such questions on Math SE.

Answer (score 0):

A linear function is one in which its output value is a *fixed multiple* of the input value for all input values. When this is true, the graph of output as a function of input yields a straight line whose *slope* is equal to the value of the fixed multiplier.